# Can't figure out why Google OAuth refresh token are expired

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-workspace, google-identity

For the last 3 weeks, we have a high number of failures when refreshing an access token with Google Oauth API. I didn't manage to figure out why this happened as it never happened to me until today.

When I tried to refresh my token I get the following HTTP response from the Google OAuth API:

```json
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked."
}
```

In the documentation, there is a section explaining the refresh token expiration: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration

> - The user has revoked your app's access.
> - The refresh token has not been used for six months.
> - The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes.
> - The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens.
> - The user belongs to a Google Cloud Platform organization that has session control policies in effect.

I went to the https://myaccount.google.com/permissions page. Since my application was still on the list it confirms that I didn't manually revoke my app's access.

The access was given on June 4, 2021, so 3 days ago (as of writing), thus it is not because the refresh token has not been used for six months.

I didn't change my password and the application does not use Gmail scopes, only the followings:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
- openid
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events

I don't know how I can verify that I have exceeded the maximum number of granted refresh tokens. But I believe I have not since other applications for which I am connected with Google work perfectly.

The only remaining item that I have to check is the session control policies in effect on my GCP organization.

But since the problem is quite new I was wondering if Google deployed something new on the Oauth (identity) API that could cause refresh tokens to expire.

Has anybody faced this issue lately?

### Update: the session control policies in effect do not require reauthenticating.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that popped up in the last four months, yes I think this is something new and there has not been any official word from Google on it yet.

Applications that are still in testing, and have not been through the google verification process will have their refresh tokens expired within in two weeks.

[image]

Comment: When you are guessing, you should post a comment.

Comment: Actually, it could be that for the development application where the problem happened to me. However, the same problem happens on our production app which is validated by Google. Thanks @DalmTo

Comment: @JohnHanley who says i am guessing?   This is something I have personally tested and there are alt least five other questions relating to this If you care to look around SO.  I have also three emails out to Googlers waiting for some official word.   Google makes changes all the time without updating the documentation.

Comment: @ben if the app has been verified then i that would suggest there is something wrong with the refresh token you are using.  I would have a look at how you are storing the refresh token make sure that it is being stored properly and completely and you are not cutting off the end or something.  As well as ensure you are always storing the most resent as orientally a new one can be returned with a refresh access token request.

Comment: @DalmTo do you mean that when refreshing an access token, Google could send a new refresh token alongside the new access token? I don't see any mention of this in the documentation. But I would completely explain my problem!

Comment: You wont find any documentation on that but I have seen in in a few cases and its not something I have been able to reproduce.   The last time was years ago when i was working with PHP.

Comment: I checked and we already store the refresh token that could be returned by Google when refreshing the access token. I found in the PHP SDK that the refresh token value is changed by whatever the response contains for it, so I think you are absolutely right about that.

I already checked the DB, we store it in a text field so I doubt the refresh is truncated.

Comment: I read something about them changing the size of one of the tokens i just cant remember which one it was.

Comment: The maximum size of Access Tokens has been increased to 2048 bytes.

Comment: Yeah that one   TBH when i store the token i often just store the full response, rather than just the refresh token, easer to feed some of the client libraries the full response.